# Maxima of sinusoid functions

Tags: calculus

We have the function $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, and we want to know the distance between the maxima. How should one tackle this? I know that the derivative is $2\cos(2x)$.

Comment: $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint; $$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$
You don't even need calculus for this, you can use your knowledge on trigonometric functions.

Comment: The 2x means that its period is twice as small, and that the maxima happen twice as often? That would mean pi

Comment: For $A\sin(bx)$, $T=\frac{2\pi}{b}$, global maxima$=|A|$

Answer (score 1):

Let's use calculus, just for fun's sake (and because you tagged it calculus). If take the zeroes of $2\cos(2x)$, then we have that $x=(2n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. Let's calculate the distance between two consecutive maxima (which will be $(2n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $(2n+5)\dfrac{\pi}{4}$).

By the distance formula, this will be
$$d=\sqrt{\left((2n+5)\dfrac{\pi}{4}-(2n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)^2+(1-1)^2}=\pi$$
(The following sentence is informally written.) If there are $n$ maxima between the two maxima that we are inputting in the equation, then we'll have $d=(n+1)\pi$. Compare to UserX's answer.

Note that this also gives the distance between the minima as well.

Comment: A useless comment; This way you could be evaluating the distance between the minima too, which of course happens to be the same. My point; First derivative being $0$ could be either a local maximum or a local minimum(in case OP gets confused for future exercises).

Comment: @UserX Yes, exactly.